# string type in strcpy() in C++

Tags: c++, string, char, strcpy

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char a[10];
    string b = "Hello"; 
    char c[] = "Hello";
    char *d = "Hello";

    strcpy(a, b); // compiler complains.
    strcpy(a, c);
    strcpy(a, d);
}
```

I know strcpy is defined as

```
char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

but if `string` type variable is same as `char*` or `char[]`, why the content of `string` type cannot be copied to `char[]`?

Answer (score 2):

A `std::string` is *not* the same as a character array.  It is a C++ object.  If you want access to it as a C string, call its [`c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) method:

```
strcpy(a, b.c_str());
```